# thmtools notebraces bug?

Tags: theorems, thmtools

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[notebraces={[}{]}]{style}
\declaretheorem[style=style]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean Theorem (Pythagoras)]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

results in

> **Theorem 1** [Pythagorean Theorem (Pythagoras])**.**

but really should be

> **Theorem 1** [Pythagorean Theorem (Pythagoras)]**.**

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  does look like a bug, so you should report it to the author of `thmtools`.  of course, you can work around the problem manually by wrapping `(Pythagoras)` in braces.

Answer (score 2):

Option `notebraces` replaces the parentheses with the given symbols with the help of macro `\thmt@embrace`:

```
\def\thmt@embrace#1#2(#3){#1#3#2}
```

Argument `#1` and `#2` are the new open and closing braces, `\thmt@embrace` is fed with the full title inclusive standard parentheses, which are detected by the parameter text `(#3)`. However, in this case, `#3` already contains `(` and `)`, thus that the detection of the correct closing `)` fails.

Workaround: Protect the inner parentheses by curly braces, as already suggested by Barbara Beeton's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262142/thmtools-notebraces-bug#comment628646_262142):

```
\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean Theorem {(Pythagoras)}]
\end{theorem}
```

The curly braces should be at least partially inside the title as in the example above to avoid automatic removal of the curly braces, when the title argument is read.

Another way is fixing `\thmthead@plain` to insert the protecting curly braces internally:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thmhead@plain}[3]{%
  \thmname{#1}%
  \thmnumber{%
    \@ifnotempty{#1}{ }%
    \@upn{#2}%
  }%
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont({#3})}}%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[notebraces={[}{]}]{style}
\declaretheorem[style=style]{theorem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}[Pythagorean Theorem (Pythagoras)]
  \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

The file `amsthm.sty` has explicit `(...)` for the note and `thmtools.sty` (better, `thm-amsthm.sty`) relies on this.

I suggest changing the delimiters, rather than bracing them, because also `\NOTE` uses it and only changing `\thmhead@plain` is not sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
%%% from amsthm.sty
\def\thmhead@plain#1#2#3{%
  \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
%%% the line below had (##3)
  \thmnote{ {\the\thm@notefont\thm@lparen#3\thm@rparen}}}

%%% from thm-amsthm.sty
\def\thmt@setheadstyle#1{%
  \thmt@style@headstyle{%
    \def\NAME{\the\thm@headfont ##1}%
    \def\NUMBER{\bgroup\@upn{##2}\egroup}%
%%% the line below had (##3)
    \def\NOTE{\if=##3=\else\bgroup\thmt@space\the\thm@notefont\thm@lparen##3\thm@rparen\egroup\fi}%
  }%
  \def\thmt@tmp{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\thmt@tmp
  %\tracingall
  \ifcsname thmt@headstyle@\thmt@tmp\endcsname
    \thmt@style@headstyle\@xa{%
      \the\thmt@style@headstyle
      \csname thmt@headstyle@#1\endcsname
    }%
  \else
    \thmt@style@headstyle\@xa{%
      \the\thmt@style@headstyle
      #1%
    }%
  \fi
  %\showthe\thmt@style@headstyle
}
%%% the line below had (#3)
\def\thmt@embrace#1#2\thm@lparen#3\thm@rparen{#1#3#2}
%%% added for default
\def\thm@lparen{(}\def\thm@rparen{)}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[notebraces={[}{]}]{style}
\declaretheorem[style=style]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean Theorem (Pythagoras)]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really know anything about that kind of stuff. So I won't accept an answer yet until I hear from the author. I send him the link to this question.